# How can i solve this problem using row and column? flutter problem

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-row

help_post
I need this problem solution.I faced some problems to solve it~I'm a fresher . I tried but it doesn't working...
[That's The problem is given by my friend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxjKU.png) and that's mine[my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRiJ3.png) sry for my bad english...

Comment: Can you add your code snippet?

Comment: The exercise proposed seems to be a main row with 3 columns. Then in each column you will have to work with paddings and some more rows. If you can share your code may be we could help you more.

Answer (score 0):

I see, that in your friends task you have 3 Columns in a Row, so your structure needs to be something like that:

```
Row(
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, //this makes your columns be an equal width from each other
children: [
  Column(),
  Column(),
  Column(),
],
);
```

You also can wrap each Column in a SizedBox and give it a width **MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.25** (so your Columns will be of one size), and you can wrap your Row in SizedBox with width **double.infinity** (to take all display width)

And next step for you is to make logic for the blocks inside each column similarly. Good luck!

Comment: thanks but i need solution of it..

Answer (score 0):

In your case, it would be easier to use [flutter_staggered_grid_view](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view) to achieve what you want, use it just one Staggered GridView or 3 in a Row:

```
StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
  crossAxisCount: 4,
  itemCount: 8,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => new Container(
      color: Colors.green,
      child: new Center(
        child: new CircleAvatar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          child: new Text('$index'),
        ),
      )),
  staggeredTileBuilder: (int index) =>
      new StaggeredTile.count(2, index.isEven ? 2 : 1),
  mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
  crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
)
```